# python connect to mysql from the third machine

Tags: python, mysql, django, paramiko

Imagine that:

I have three machine. M1 has my client program.M3 is mysql server. But M1 can not connect M3 directly. M1 can access M2 using ssh or something else directly. M2 can access M3 directly. Well, how do client program on M1 to connect mysql server M3 through M2 using python and execute sql, such as `select clause`. Is it possible and how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/) can be useful in your case - it's only an alpha.

In another way, you can bing the port of mysql of M3 on M2 using [SSH port forwarding](http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-use-ssh-local-and-remote-port-forwarding.html).

The default TCP port for MySQL is [3306](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connecting.html). The relevant SSH command line would be

```
ssh M2 -L M1_port:M3:3306
```

(where you need to substitute M2 with the hostname/IP address of M2 and have M1_port as some previously unused port at M1, for example 3306 if you don't run an MySQL server at M1)

Your MySQL client at M1 should connect to M1/localhost via port `M1_port`, and all of this traffic will be tunnelled to M3 at port 3306.

Comment: @Uri Yanover: thank for sampling the port forwarding.

Comment: It is not using python.